# Photoshop: How do you nudge multiple times and still count as a single action?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is something that was driving me mad and just now figure I could ask here.

In previous versions of Photoshop, I could nudge elements by hitting `Shift+Arrow` and the whole nudging counted as a single action in history state. If I paused, then it would add another action to history, but only then.

Now, in Photoshop CC, each time I hit the arrow key, it counts as a new history state. So, if I hit the arrow key 100 times, I have to go back 100 states in history, which is crazy. See capture below:

[image]

I tried looking at different options to no avail. Maybe I'm too dumb, but really can't find it, and it would be amazing to get it back to what it was (hopefully they didn't *kill* this feature)

So... **is it possible to group all these actions in a single one?**

Comment: If nudge is equivalent to move object 1 pixel in 1 direction than you can Transform>Move in A direction for B number of pixels, which would be 1 action. This doesn't let you see and choose the tween states like nudge would, but you can keep on trying values until your object is positioned correctly. I feel this is more precise and conducive to alignment anyway.

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, but my Photoshop CC2017 records 1 history state for Nudge, even if I nudge 100 times. It only creates a new state if I switch tools or do something else in between nudging.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it always was, but somehow now it records each stroke, so I figure there must be something I have to check/uncheck, but can't find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-installing PS 3 times, I have found the answer at **[Photoshop forum](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/how-to-disable-multiple-nugle-items-in-the-history)**

In my case, I solved it by going to `Preferences --> Plugins`

Once inside that section, I unchecked **"Load Extension Panels"**, re-started Photoshop and *voilá*, it worked!

The only difference with that answer is that I kept `Generator` alive, further tests shown the problem came with **Creative Cloud**. The problematic version is running on Windows, but CC on my Mac seems to work fine, just as expected